# Consulta DQL utilizando oneToMany no WHERE

Tags: php, doctrine, dql

Essa consulta não funciona:

```
public function getByUnidadeAnoSemestre(int $unidadeId, int $ano, int $semestre) : array
{
    $query = $this->em->createQuery(
        'SELECT s,u,p FROM ' . 
            Servico::class . ' s ' .
        'INNER JOIN ' . 
            's.unidade u ' . 
        'INNER JOIN ' . 
            's.precificacoes p ' .
        'WHERE ' . 
            'u.id = :unidadeId ' . 
            'AND p.anoLetivo = :ano ' . 
            'AND p.semestre = :semestre'
    )->setParameters([
        "unidadeId" => $unidadeId,
        "anoLetivo" => $ano,
        "semestre" => $semestre
    ]);

    return $query->getResult();

}
```

Os mapeamentos na classe Servico estão assim:

```
/**
* @OneToMany(targetEntity="Precificacao", mappedBy="precificacoes", cascade={"persist"})
* @var Collection 
*/
private $precificacoes;

/**
* @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Unidade", inversedBy="id", cascade={"persist"})
* @JoinColumn(name="unidadeId", referencedColumnName="id")
* @var Unidade 
*/
private $unidade;
```

A mensagem de erro no Slim é

> "Type of association must be one of *_TO_ONE or MANY_TO_MANY"

E o erro no console do Php é

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: precificacoes in D:\Projetos\FinanceiroEscolarApi\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker.php on line 946

Podem me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui descobrir o problema. Era o mapeamento One-To-Many Bidirecional entre Servico e Precificacao.

Deixei a classe Servico assim

```
/**
* @OneToMany(targetEntity="Precificacao", mappedBy="servico", cascade={"persist"})
* @var Collection 
*/
private $precificacoes;
```

E a classe Precificacao assim

```
/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Servico", inversedBy="precificacoes", cascade={"persist"})
 * @JoinColumn(name="servicoId", referencedColumnName="id")
 * @var Servico
 */
private $precificacoes;
```

Depois corrigi a consulta

```
public function getByUnidadeAnoSemestre(int $unidadeId, int $ano, int $semestre) : array
{
    $query = $this->em->createQuery(
        'SELECT s,u,p FROM ' . 
            Servico::class . ' s ' .
        'INNER JOIN ' . 
            's.unidade u ' . 
        'INNER JOIN ' . 
            's.precificacoes p ' .
        'WHERE ' . 
            'u.id = :unidadeId ' . 
        'AND p.anoLetivo = :ano ' . 
            'AND p.semestre = :semestre'
        )->setParameters([
            "unidadeId" => $unidadeId,
            "ano" => $ano,
            "semestre" => $semestre
        ]);

    return $query->getResult();
}
```